# angular showing this type of error how I resolve this?

Tags: angular

More than one module matches. Use the skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module or use the module option to specify a module.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have more modules (app-module and others made by you) and a component is imported into app-module, but also in one of your modules. You must delete the wrong import. DISCLAIMER: one component can be imported only in one module. If you want to use one component in more modules, you can make a "shared" module that is imported and exported, so these are some global components that you can use anywhere.